# Do we have some shell tools like makefile that supports nested subcommands?

Tags: shell, go, taskfile

For example, I just need to edit the config file like the following:

```
clean:
  rpc:
    rm -rf ./rpc
  api
    rm -rf ./api
```

run:

```
> make clean rpc
```

However, `make` don't support nested subcommands.

A good choice is `https://github.com/spf13/cobra`, which supports `subcommands` and `command alias`... But it is used in golang, not shell.

I wonder do we have`cobra` in shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I wonder do we have cobra in shell?`

I found 1,
This is the link: https://taskfile.dev/#/

Below is the example:

`Taskfile.yml`

```yaml
version: "3"

tasks:
  clean:rpc:
    desc: Clean RPC
    cmds:
      - rm -rf ./rpc

  clean:api:
    desc: Clean API
    cmds:
      - rm -rf ./api
```

To view available commands: `task --list`
To exec command: `task clean:api` or `task clean:rpc`